# What are the consequences of mutating event.target.value (in React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Let's say we are building custom input component.

In this component, as an example let's say we want to change the value from a string to a number

```
const CustomInputComponent = ({ onChange, ...rest }) => {
  const onChangeHandler = (event)=>{
    // What are the consequences of doing this?
    event.target.value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    onChange(event);
  }
  return <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
}
```

What are the consequences of directly mutating `event.target.value` like this?

Comment: None, I would assume, since the `value` property of an input will always be coerced to a string I would think. But where's the gain of this? If you really think this component's consumers will always pass an `onChange` handler which relies on the `event.target.value` being a number, you can always do something like `const modifiedEvent = { ...event, { target: { ...event.target, value: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) }}; onChange(modifiedEvent);`. Though that looks disgusting enough I just wouldn't bother and assume consumers know how the DOM works!

Comment: actually, there could well be unintended consequences if the user enters a non-numeric string (as the `parseInt` call will result in `NaN`)

Comment: @RobinZigmond You'll want to make that an answer

Comment: @Bergi fair point - I probably will do shortly :)

Answer (score 5):

> What are the consequences of directly mutating event.target.value like this?

They're exactly what you would expect: the value of the input gets changed to the new value.

Granted, if you assume that the user enters a numeric value, there won't be any noticeable output - because although you're overwriting the `event.target.value` from say the string `"1"` to the number `1`, that will get coerced back to a string inside the input, because input values can only ever be strings.

But, if the user types anything else, you'll get strange-looking - and I can only assume unintended - consequences. See the demo below where I've set up a simple render of your component (with an `onChange` function prop that does nothing - this is just to illustrate your component without it crashing and makes no difference here), and observe for yourself the consequences (spelled out below the snippet).

```js
const CustomInputComponent = ({ onChange, ...rest }) => {
  const onChangeHandler = (event)=>{
    // What are the consequences of doing this?
    event.target.value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    onChange(event);
  }
  return <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
}

const App = () => <CustomInputComponent onChange={()=>{}} />;

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

- as previously observed, if you enter the character `"1"`, it gets displayed as expected.
- if you then enter a non-numeric character, it won't appear at all. This is because the when you type `"a"` here, say, the `event.target.value` is `"1a"`, and `parseInt("1a", 10)` is equal to `1`. (`parseInt` is different from coercion via `Number` in that it will read whatever numeric values it can from the start of the string and just stop processing when it hits a character it can't parse.) So the value gets set to `1`, the same as it was before.
- if you enter any non-numeric content, including simply by deleting the above (to leave `event.target.value` as the empty string), or by resetting to the start and entering a non-numeric character, the output will become `NaN`. That's because strings which don't even begin with a numeric character, including the empty string, return `NaN` ("not a number", although confusingly that value has type `number`) when `parseInt` is used.

So no, you don't want to do this.

The only value - assuming it's acceptable to you for things to go so wonky as this with non-numeric input - seems to be to allow consumers of this prop to provide an `onChange` which directly acts on numbers without having to convert from string to number inside the function itself. This seems an incredibly weak benefit to me, for the following reasons:

1. your component is an `<input type="text" />` without even an `inputmode="numeric"` to suggest numeric input is required. There's absolutely no reason to expect users won't want to type non-numeric characters here - and even if you give it a label and description that make abundantly clear only numbers are allowed, users are still going to do it (if only by committing typos), and expect the input to appear. You want to give an error message in these circumstances, not force the input to change it to something else.
2. even if this is supposed to be a numeric input, anyone with any experience of developing with HTML and Javascript knows full well that `event.target.value` is *always* a string. Even if they want to do numeric things with that string, they'll fully expect to have to do the conversion to a number themselves.
3. if despite the above, you *really* want to provide an event object to the `onChange` function prop which has a number for it's target value, you can do it without mutating the existing event object, for example like this:

```
const modifiedEvent = { ...event, target: { ...event.target, value: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) }};
onChange(modifiedEvent);
```

And well I find that line of code kind-of disgusting - although you can probably make it less horrendous, perhaps with some helper libraries that are specifically designed for immutable "updates" like this. But for me really it's yet another reason, if one were really needed, not to do this. Having said that, even the above is *much* better than the direct mutation of `event.target.value` that you're asking about.

Comment: tldr; any shorter explanation?

Comment: The most important information about why not to do this is in the runnable code snippet - see the bullet points immediately after if you need help figuring it out.

Comment: The 'modifiedEvent' code snippet is supposed to be "const modifiedEvent = { ...event, target: { ...event.target, value: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) }};"

Cause the one above as of today - 12/02/2022 doesn't work.

Comment: Oops sorry you're right, I'll edit. Thanks!